# How to select value from the cells of the largest second level index of every first level index?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following dataframe which I now wish to create an additional column to contain the destination (`ziel`) of every train (as the 1st level row index `zug_nr`), which is already in the `an_bf` column as the last stop of every train (as the 2nd level row index `bf`).

However, using `groupby` doesn't help

```
df9['ziel'] = df9['an_bf'].groupby(level = 0, axis = 0).max()
df9.head()

             an_zeit            an_bf           sorte  ab_zeit     ziel
zug_nr  bf                  
IC 2309 0   1900-01-01 00:11:00 Duisburg Hbf    IC  1900-01-01 00:00:00 NaN
        1   1900-01-01 00:25:00 Düsseldorf Hbf  IC  1900-01-01 00:00:00 NaN
        2   1900-01-01 00:49:00 Köln Hbf        IC  1900-01-01 00:00:00 NaN
ICE 100 0   1900-01-01 00:13:00 Bochum Hbf      ICE 1900-01-01 00:04:00 NaN
        1   1900-01-01 00:26:00 Dortmund Hbf    ICE 1900-01-01 00:04:00 NaN
```

Here is how I'd like it to be:

```
             an_zeit            an_bf           sorte  ab_zeit     ziel
zug_nr  bf                  
IC 2309 0   1900-01-01 00:11:00 Duisburg Hbf    IC  1900-01-01 00:00:00 Köln Hbf
        1   1900-01-01 00:25:00 Düsseldorf Hbf  IC  1900-01-01 00:00:00 Köln Hbf
        2   1900-01-01 00:49:00 Köln Hbf        IC  1900-01-01 00:00:00 Köln Hbf
ICE 100 0   1900-01-01 00:13:00 Bochum Hbf      ICE 1900-01-01 00:04:00 Dortmund Hbf
        1   1900-01-01 00:26:00 Dortmund Hbf    ICE 1900-01-01 00:04:00 Dortmund Hbf
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
#if datetimes are not sorted by an_zeit column
#df9 = df9.sort_values('an_zeit', ascending=False)

df9['ziel'] = df9.groupby(level=0)['an_bf'].transform('last')

#sorting MultiIndex if necessary
#df9 = df9.sort_index()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!
The order is fine, it is sorted by `ab_zeit`, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You should using `transform`

```
df9['ziel'] = df9['an_bf'].groupby(level = 0, axis = 0).transform('max')
```